# Wordpress custom url

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-url, pretty-urls

I have this URL (www.yourdomain.com/view-promotion/123) which will use the **Page Template** to display my **Custom Post Type** content. 
**(123 is the CPT post id)**

However, if I change the URL from the above to (www.yourdomain.com/view-promotion/christmas-promotion).

The url will automatically switched to (www.yourdomain.com/promotion/christmas-promotion) using the **Custom Post Type Template**

**Additional Info**

- view-promotion is the page name
- promotion is the post_type
- christmas-promotion is the post name

What should I do so that I could change the URL to (www.yourdomain.com/view-promotion/christmas-promotion) which will using the layout from the **Page Template**??

Comment: if you changed your post type rewrite to `view-promotion` you could probably achieve the same. What you really need to do is have a look at the code creating the post type and start learning how to use it. This website is more for providing coding help rather than general answers to non-coding problems.

Comment: Apologies. I thought I might need to use Custom URL rewrite code to do the job or something. I am not really sure what other alternatives I could use. Hence, asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but this is a long struggle. You can install plugin for this easly. Your need this plugin: [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Install this plugin and change permalink setting in **settings > permalinks.**

Comment: That plugin is actually setting the URL to (www.yourdomain.com/promotion/christmas-promotion) which is not what I am trying to achieve.

What if I were to change the URL to (www.yourdomain.com/view-promotion/?promo=christmas-promotion) but rewrite to show as (www.yourdomain.com/view-promotion/christmas-promotion)??

Would that be more feasible to implement?

Comment: You can change permalink slug with codes. While you add new post type, your `register_post_type` function has **rewrite** and this array has **slug** field. Your code should be like this:
`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'shiba-gallery', 'with_front' => FALSE)`